# C - Print list of Prime Numbers (recursion)

Tags: c, if-statement, recursion, primes

I'm having some problems with this C programming assignment that I have in school. I'm supposed to return the prime numbers from within a given range, and it has to be done using recursion.

The code I've got so far is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int primeNumberList(int n, int m, int z);

int main() {
    int n1 = 0,
        n2 = 10,
        d = 2;

    printf("n1 = %d | n2 = %d | d = %d\n\n", n1, n2, d);    
    printf("Prime Numbers between %d and %d are: \n", n1, n2);

    primeNumberList(n1, n2, d);

    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}

int primeNumberList(int n, int m, int z) {
    int notPrime = 0;

    if (n <= 1) {
        primeNumberList(n + 1, m, z);
    } else
    if (n < m) {
        if (z <= n / 2) {
            if (n % z == 0) {
                notPrime = 1;
                z = 2;
            } else {
                primeNumberList(n, m, z + 1);
            }
        }
        if (notPrime == 0) {
            printf("%d ", n);
        }
        primeNumberList(n + 1, m, z);
    }
}
```

What happens when I run this, is that after it's gone through all the numbers up to the limit (in the function it's `m` (`n2` in `main`)) it won't break the recursion, but somehow manage to subtract numbers from `n`, and starts printing some other numbers that are not prime numbers. 
When I run it in debug, it seems to be looping at the end, but there's nothing there to loop... I've tried adding a `return 0;` or even a `printf` with some text, but it ignores it completely.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong here? Why doesn't it stop when `n < m`?

Comment: `primeNumberList` has no `return` statement?

Comment: Indentation under the if(z <= n/2) block is flat

Comment: @Ben: Using a "return 0;" or "return;" doesn't work either, if that's what you meant, or did you mean that the value should be assigned to a variable that is returned?

Comment: @Christoffer You have the potential to make two recursive calls for each call, which is what is messing you up I think. For now, adding `if(n == m-1) exit(1);` at the beginning of `primeNumberList` is a hacky solution that works.

Comment: @River: Thanks a lot, that works as it should! You mentioned it's a hacky solution, does that mean that you normally shouldn't use it, or is it just because my coding is a little messy and therefore it's easier to use it than the alternative?.

Comment: @Christoffer I found a real solution for you (posted as answer below). "Hacky" just means it is a practice that is generally bad coding and shouldn't be used. A forced exit should never be how you escape from recursion, it's just bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found your problem. You have the potential to make two recursive calls for each time you call `primeNumberList`.

After you return from `primeNumberList(n, m, z+1);` (under the innermost `else`) you still can go on to print a prime and do a call to `primeNumberList(n+1, m, z);`. This is not the behavior you want, you want to return directly after this inner `else` call.

So simply add a `return` before each of your calls to `primeNumberList` (`primeNumberList(x);` becomes `return primeNumberList(x);`) and also a `return 0` at the end of this function (this last `return` is just to make the compiler happy).

Answer (score 1):

Try something cleaner: defining a separate isPrime function and calling it.

http://www.cquestions.com/2011/08/prime-number-program-in-c-using.html

```
int isPrime(int num,int i){

  if(i==1){
      return 1;
  }else{
     if(num%i==0)
       return 0;
     else
       isPrime(num,i-1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive function exit criteria is not right.

When you you call the recursive function, it winds up, then down.  When I run your code through step by step, As it is winding *up*, I get the complete list of primes, as following:
[image]

Then as it continues and the following digits, are printed:
[image]

***Your question***: *Why doesn't it stop when n < m?*
Because as you start unwinding, the values stored in the value `n` also start unwinding down through the iterations of the recursions that have been called, allowing execution flow to stay in the loop.
Further more, if unwind brings execution flow to a point that passes the `printf("%d ", n);` statement, the value for `n`, whatever it is at that *unwind* iteration, will be printed out.

One way way to leave without printing anything beyond `n == 10` is to create a bypass variable, and use it as a criteria for printing:

```
static done = 0;
```

Then set `done` to 1 when you do not want to print any more values as it is unwinding.

Here is a modified function that will do this:

```
int primeNumberList(int n, int m, int z) {
    int notPrime = 0;
    static done = 0;//add a bypass variable, init to zero

    if (n <= 1) {
        primeNumberList(n + 1, m, z);
    } 
    else
    {
        if(n == 10)
            {
                done = 1; //at this point all primes (except 1) are printed
                          //so set done to 1
            }
        if (n < m) 
        {
            if (z <= n / 2) 
            {
                if (n % z == 0) 
                {
                    notPrime = 1;
                    z = 2;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    primeNumberList(n, m, z + 1);
                }
            }
            if ((notPrime == 0) && (!done)) //test done before printing
            {
                printf("%d ", n);
            }
            primeNumberList(n + 1, m, z);
        }
    }
    return 0;//add this return statement
}
```